# Nuxt 3 - redirecting in script setup

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3, nuxt3

With following code sometimes I need to redirect to '/my/path', and it works,
but before the redirect hits, user can see this page for few milliseconds (Text you shouldn't see), and then they get redirected to 'my/path' as expected. But the problem here is how to prevent rendering of current page text, so user could only see '/my/path'

```
// page.vue
<script setup>

const someCondition = ....

if (someCondition) {
  navigateTo({ path: '/my/path' }, { external: true }) 
}

// ... lots of some other stuff
</script>
<template>
Text you shouldn't see if someCondition is true
</template>
```

Had identical code in Nuxt 2, but it worked as expected.

UPD:

Rewrote code this way:

```
definePageMeta({
  layout: false,
  middleware: ['redir-to-mypath'],
})
<template>
  <div v-if="!someCondition">
  ...
  </div>
</template>
```

But it like changed nothing, leaaly confused here.

Answer (score 2):

Nuxt3 offers you the chance to set up a middleware which should exactly do what you are looking for.

Reference: https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/middleware

You can set up something like this:

```
export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware((to: any, from: any) => {
    const nuxtApp = useNuxtApp()

    if(process.server) {    
        host = nuxtApp.ssrContext?.event.node.req.headers.host
    } else {
        host = window.location.host
    }

   if(host.indexOf('xyz') < 0) {
       return navigateTo(`/xyz/test`)
   }

 })
```

Therefore you sort this out before the rendering of the page actually occurs.

Hope it helps

Comment: Problem i that i need this behaviour only on single page

Comment: It is not a problem, inside the middleware you can check if the route is the one you need and then intervene only in that case. If you want a "dirtier" solutions you should just use a specific layout for that page and do the onBeforeMount in the layout, before the page is rendered

Comment: @Dfr you can configure middleware to apply only to specific pages, rather than globally, similar to your Nuxt2 example. https://nuxt.com/docs/examples/routing/middleware

Comment: exactly as @NikoChaffin said. Generally speaking, and as best practice, route checks and similar things SHOULD be done in a middleware, that's precisely why they were made in the first place

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onBeforeMount`, which runs your condition before the DOM is generated. This likely was an issue with your old code, but something is different now - something is running a bit slower, your machine is a bit slower or you're on a different one, etc.

https://vuejs.org/api/composition-api-lifecycle.html#onbeforemount

```
<script setup>
import { onBeforeMount } from "vue";

onBeforeMount(() => {
    if (someCondition) navigateTo({ path: '/my/path' }, { external: true }) ;
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, but this doesn't change anything unfortunately, maybe it's Nuxt 3 related somehow

Comment: You could also just hide the text behind a `v-if` and have a component that shows instead that informs them they're being redirected.

Comment: This doesnt help as well, so confusing

Comment: It worked well for me, but I added `await` before the navigateTo function. Despite that, it is redirecting well without issues.

Answer (score 0):

Using middleware is the best option.

Page defined middleware e.g.

```js
<script lang="ts" setup>
definePageMeta({
  middleware: [
    function(to, from) {
      // Run your conditions here.
    }
  ]
})
</script>
```

If you really don't want to use middlware, you can do use the `page:finish` hook.

```js
<script lang="ts" setup>
const displayContent = ref(false)
if (someCOndition) {
  navigateTo('/')
}
onMounted(() => {
  useNuxtApp().hook('page:finish', () => {
    displayContent.value = true
  })
})
</script>
<template>
  <div v-if="displayContent">
    <!-- Start of content -->
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: The additional problem is layout, it gets rendered before this actual page, but it just adds to the mess